# How to return nicely-formatted text in beautifulsoup4 when HTML text is across multiple lines

Tags: html, regex, beautifulsoup, python-3.6

I'm trying to extract an address using python's beautifulsoup4 package. The HTML block where the text is located looks like:

```
<address>
        183 Main St<br>East Copper<br>Massachusetts<br>U S A<br>
        MA 01516-113
    </address>
```

I'm able to grab the address using the find and text.strip() method and replacing \n and \r with nothing, but I'm getting back:

```
'183 Main StEast CopperMassachusettsU S A        MA 01516-113'
```

This is probably OK for my purposes but curiosity makes me want to understand how to clean it up.

I've done significant tinkering and research to figure out how I can get it to return a nicely formatted address. What I mean by that is all on one line (as it is currently), without the extra spaces and WITH the spaces supposed to be between things like "Copper" and "Massachusetts".

Am I thinking about this incorrectly by thinking a regex expression/code could help? Should I instead be iterating through the `<br>` tags and grabbing each line individually then combining the strings with `+` and spaces?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It looks like you are getting words jammed together by replacing <br> tags and newlines with nothing. Perhaps replace them with a single space. Then go through the string and replace more than one continuous spaces with a single space. You'll probably still see issues, but will perhaps look a little better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In such cases the ideal way to go is something like below:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

content="""
<address>
        183 Main St<br>East Copper<br>Massachusetts<br>U S A<br>
        MA 01516-113
    </address>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(content,"lxml")
item = soup.find("address").get_text(" ",strip=True)
print(item)
```

Output:

```
183 Main St East Copper Massachusetts U S A MA 01516-113
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked for me. Can you give a brief explanation as to why this is different than the `text.strip()` method while replacing `\n` and `\r` ?

Comment: It strips the leading and trailing whitespaces no matter how big they are. Check out [this link](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text) for the clarity.

Comment: Thanks again really appreciate it